# How to show vi mode in prompt with tcsh

Tags: shell, prompt, vi, tcsh

I use vi keybindings when working within my terminal shell to keep continuity between my shell and vim editor. Because of IT requirements, I need to now switch to tcsh from bash and zsh and I am looking at recreating some of my configurations within tcsh. The biggest friction point that I have hit now is that I can't view which vi mode I am currently in within my prompt which can lead to unexpected behavior when I am working. Through zsh and bash there is a lot of information on how to achieve this. I haven't been able to find anything about tcsh except for [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/18583/how-to-show-the-current-vi-mode-when-using-vi-keybindings-in-the-shell). I wasn't able to work through the only answer that actually provided an answer. What can I do to retrieve my vi mode (insert/normal) I am in when using the tcsh shell?

Comment: I think this might be really tricky and hacky; the roadblocks are that you need to 1) get the current vi mode somehow (not sure how? Possibly override the standard keybinds, set a variable, and use that; this on its own would be hacky) and 2) display that in `$prompt` somehow, but since there's no way to eval anything in the prompt this would be hard as well (the usual strategy is to hook in to the special `precmd`/`postcmd` aliases which source a script that re-sets `prompt`, but that won't work for line editing, so not sure how to do this either). I'm afraid you might be out of luck here :-(

Comment: tl;dr is that tcsh is kind of an old shell with a lot of limitations; it's not super-bad for interactive use (and actually has some nice features), but if you want to do more advanced custom stuff like you can with bash or zsh then things get very difficult and very ugly very fast. I don't know what kind of requirements/motivations your IT department has, but I would personally try to either get them to change it, or just circumvent it by using a statically compiled `zsh` binary. I don't know if those are options for you though.

Comment: If they're not, I think the easiest is probably to accept that this part if your life sucks a bit more from now on :-( The universe is not always kind.